# How to use type inheritance for middlewares?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-functions, middleware

First question here, hope I'm doing it right.

I'm working on serverless backend functions and there's some functionality we've put in middlewares but I'm struggling to get inheritance to work as expected and was hoping to get some help.

What I'm trying to do:
I want to have a whole bunch of fully typed middlewares to avoid Human error when creating a new endpoint. We do have quite a lot of reusable bits and they made our life a lot easier.
We use 2 types of middlewares: some write data into the context (i.e. withSession) and others just read (i.e. withErrorLogging)

The Javascript part of it **works** so this is purely a TS question.

Here's what I have so far:

```
type Context<T> = {
  prop1: string;
} & T;

type Handler<T> = {
  (ctx: Context<T>): Promise<void>;
};

type Middleware<RequiredProps, AddedProps = any> = {
  <T extends RequiredProps>(handler: Handler<T & AddedProps>): Handler<T & AddedProps>;
};

const withErrorLogging: Middleware<any> = (handler) => {
  return async (props) => {
    try {
      return await handler(props);
    } catch (e) {
      // do something special
    }
  };
};

const withSession: Middleware<{}, { session: "session" }> = (handler) => {
  return (ctx) => {
    return handler({ ...ctx, session: "session" });
  };
};

// requires a `pid` prop to be available in the request
const withProject: Middleware<{ pid: number }, { project: Project }> = (handler) => {
  return async (ctx) => {
    const project = await getProjectById(ctx, ctx.pid);
    if (!project) {
      // return 404
    }
    return handler({ ...ctx, project });
  };
};

// Currently I have to specify all middleware results in the HandlerProps  
// I want the types here to become automatic depending on what middlewares are called
type HandlerProps = {
  pid: number;
  session: "session";
  project: Project;
};

export const handler = withErrorLogging(
  withSession(
    withProject(async (ctx: HandlerProps) => {
      ctx.pid; // exists in TS
      ctx.session; // exists in TS
      ctx.project; // exists in TS
    })
  )
);
```

But of course this is cheating, in a perfect world I'd write only the routes params and the middlewares would inject the data, something like:

```
type HandlerProps = {
  pid: number;
};

export const handler = withErrorLogging(
  withSession(
    withProject<HandlerProps >(async (ctx) => {
      ctx.pid; // exists in TS
      ctx.session; // exists in TS
      ctx.project; // exists in TS
    })
  )
);
```

The more I think about it, the more it seems this is not possible.
I've considered using other formats like:

```
export const handler2 = withErrorLogging(async (ctx: Context<HandlerProps>) => {
  const session = await withSession(ctx);
  const project = await withProject(ctx.pid);
});
```

But then I'd need to repeat a lot of error handling and it'll eventually become a mess:

```
if no session return 401
if no project return 404 
etc
```

Also tried an express-like approach but didn't get far without facing the same problems...

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your express-like approach? That's how it should be done. You shouldn't create middleware that takes a handler - that's not actually middleware, it's a [decorated] handler function - as an argument, it should accept req, res, next and call next when it's done doing it's job. Terminology matters a little bit, your "with error logging" isn't middleware